# apache vhost config for Phalcon

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, phalcon, vhosts

I have problems with `vhost` configuration for my phalcon app. I want `localhost`address to be pointed to `var/www/html/public`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin admin@example.host
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"
DirectoryIndex index.php
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost

<Directory "/var/www/html/public">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to `localhost` I see `"Mod-Rewrite is not enabled"` but when I type `localhost/public` it goes into public catalog which I want to be `root`.

Comment: Did you create your project with `Phalcon-devtools` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create your project with [Phalcon Dev Tools](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tools.html), an .htaccess file will be created in root of your project instead of `/public` directory and the content of it is equal to :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So first you must change the `DocumentRoot` to:
`/var/www/html`
Then add the above code in your `.htaccess` file.

I recommend you to use `PhalconDevTools` for better experience  & result.

GoodLuck